# inner join query of two tables not giving exact result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables such as `vw_ad_vehicle_details` and `vw_ad_mobile_phones`

```
$query = $this->db->select('AV.Title,AV.Description,AV.Price,AV.Created_Date,AMP.Title,AMP.Description,AMP.Price,AMP.Created_Date')
              ->distinct()
             ->from('vw_ad_vehicle AV')
             ->join('vw_ad_mobile_phones AMP','AV.Created_By = AMP.Created_By','inner')
             ->where('AV.Created_By and', $_SESSION['jobseeker_id'])
              ->where('AMP.Created_By',$_SESSION['jobseeker_id'])
             ->get();
            $applied_count=$query->num_rows();
            $applied_data=$query->result_array();
            var_dump($applied_data);
```

It not gives the data from mobile table it only gives me the data from vehicle table
`var_dump($applied_data)` shows me

```
array (size=22)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New nokia lumia 630' (length=19)
      'Description' => string 'new mobile is on sale' (length=21)
      'Price' => string '9876.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 15:42:07' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New nokia lumia 630' (length=19)
      'Description' => string 'new mobile is on sale' (length=21)
      'Price' => string '9876.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 15:42:07' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia X' (length=7)
      'Description' => string 'new mobile is on sale' (length=21)
      'Price' => string '7623.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:32:27' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia X' (length=7)
      'Description' => string 'new mobile is on sale' (length=21)
      'Price' => string '7623.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:32:27' (length=19)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia 1100' (length=10)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia 1100 who is having blue body' (length=34)
      'Price' => string '1250.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:32:54' (length=19)
  5 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia 1100' (length=10)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia 1100 who is having blue body' (length=34)
      'Price' => string '1250.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:32:54' (length=19)
  6 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia X2-01' (length=11)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia X2-01 with headphone n charger' (length=36)
      'Price' => string '3999.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:33:05' (length=19)
  7 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia X2-01' (length=11)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia X2-01 with headphone n charger' (length=36)
      'Price' => string '3999.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:33:05' (length=19)
  8 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia 6600' (length=10)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia 6600 with gud quality' (length=27)
      'Price' => string '8777.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:33:19' (length=19)
  9 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia 6600' (length=10)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia 6600 with gud quality' (length=27)
      'Price' => string '8777.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:33:19' (length=19)
  10 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia 3300' (length=10)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia black 3300 with battery n headset' (length=39)
      'Price' => string '4532.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:34:01' (length=19)
  11 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Nokia 3300' (length=10)
      'Description' => string 'Nokia black 3300 with battery n headset' (length=39)
      'Price' => string '4532.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:34:01' (length=19)
  12 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New nokia lumia' (length=15)
      'Description' => string 'new mobile is on sale' (length=21)
      'Price' => string '10234.00' (length=8)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:34:13' (length=19)
  13 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New nokia lumia' (length=15)
      'Description' => string 'new mobile is on sale' (length=21)
      'Price' => string '10234.00' (length=8)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 16:34:13' (length=19)
  14 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New nokia lumia' (length=15)
      'Description' => string 'sagj' (length=4)
      'Price' => string '12763.00' (length=8)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 18:13:45' (length=19)
  15 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New nokia lumia' (length=15)
      'Description' => string 'sagj' (length=4)
      'Price' => string '12763.00' (length=8)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-19 18:13:45' (length=19)
  16 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New Nokia XL' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'sdfjk' (length=5)
      'Price' => string '7867.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-22 12:47:17' (length=19)
  17 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New Nokia XL' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'sdfjk' (length=5)
      'Price' => string '7867.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-22 12:47:17' (length=19)
  18 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New Nokia XL' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'sdfjk' (length=5)
      'Price' => string '7867.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-22 12:48:18' (length=19)
  19 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'New Nokia XL' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'sdfjk' (length=5)
      'Price' => string '7867.00' (length=7)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-22 12:48:18' (length=19)
  20 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Brand New Nokia Lumia 630' (length=25)
      'Description' => string 'vdsv' (length=4)
      'Price' => string '12438.00' (length=8)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-23 19:41:51' (length=19)
  21 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Title' => string 'Brand New Nokia Lumia 630' (length=25)
      'Description' => string 'vdsv' (length=4)
      'Price' => string '12438.00' (length=8)
      'Created_Date' => string '2014-05-23 19:41:51' (length=19)
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select()` function is wrong ,second parameter of select is for escaping ,first parameter contains the list of columns in select statement

```
$this->db->select('AV.Title,AV.Description,AV.Price,AV.Created_Date,','AMP.Title,AMP.Description,AMP.Price,AMP.Created_Date')
                                                                     ^^^^ here
```

Try this

```
$this->db->select('AV.Title,AV.Description,AV.Price,AV.Created_Date,AMP.Title,AMP.Description,AMP.Price,AMP.Created_Date')
```

**Edit**

You have similar column names in your both tables you also need to give unique aliases to them like below

```
$this->db->select('
AV.Title,
AV.Description,
AV.Price,
AV.Created_Date,
AMP.Title AS AMPTitle,
AMP.Description AS AMPDescription,
AMP.Price AS  AMPPrice,
AMP.Created_Date AS AMPCreated_Date'
)
```

Comment: k wait i will check it and let you know

Comment: it shows me the data from mobile table and not from vehicle table but while showing the data it shows each rows twice or two times it display the same row

Comment: If i did the changes as per you said then it gives me above data in var_dump()

Comment: k wait i will check it

Comment: @OmkarHendre what does var_dump() says this time and what the error ?

Comment: It gives me above result after making the changes as you said

Comment: @OmkarHendre can you show what code you are trying the above resultset is not possible by the code i have provided

Comment: brother i show the code and the retrieve data in var_dump at above

Comment: Actually i want the data from two table such as ad_vehicles and ad_mobile_phone where Created_By = users session id